# How do you crop a video into a square dimension without using FFmpeg?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, video-processing

I would like to take a video file and crop it to output a square video.

Use case: Take a video in landscape, crop the center part and save the square video output in file.

I know you can do it using NDK + FFmpeg but I would like to find out if there are other alternatives using pure Java. Anyone?